# {{ content }} Liquid tag not showing blog posts

Tags: html, tags, jekyll, shopify, liquid

Link to repo: https://github.com/AlvSovereign/AlvSovereign.github.io

I am coding my portfolio site, with a link to my blog. The fully processed portfolio site sits in `_site/index.html` which contains a link to the blog (fully processed link exists in _site/blog.html)

Blog.html at the root of the repo has in the front matter a layout of "bl", which is defined in my layouts folder under "**bl.html**".

"**bl.html**" is the layout I want for my blog page, which contains my includes etc. It also contains the `{{ content }}` liquid tag.

If I am thinking about this the right way, my posts are being parsed (I think this is the right terminology) into "**post.html**" - which has the front matter "layout: bl", which then parsed into "bl.html", and that this is so as they both have `{{ content }}` in each files.

Now all my posts are showing correctly (i think) within `_site/(year)/(month)` etc. However, they are not ending being parsed through my "blog.html" file, and then visible on my webpage. How I know this is that the fully processed "**blog.html**" file does not have any of the posts in them.

What will I need to do to solve this issue?

If it helps, I use Prepros for LiveReload, and using LANYON template, http://lanyon.getpoole.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ content }}` refers to all the content that in the file that is being converted to HTML code.

For example, if you are passing a blog post on 'What is Jekyll' to any layout that has the `{{ content }}` tag, all text other than the YAML front matter will be put in that place. Basically the content of the post. You can also limit the scope by using `{{ post.content }}`, see `Variables` for more info [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/).

So the Liquid {{ content }} variable works as intended.

Looking at your website, I believe you're trying to display all the posts in your `blog.html` file, so what you're actually asking about is **why aren't my posts being displayed (not parsed) in your blog.html file, hence not visible on your webpage.**

The reason for that is because you shouldn't use `{{ content }}` tag for that, what you want instead is something like this snippet of code [as mentioned in the Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#displaying-an-index-of-posts), that will grab all your posts, and display them by post title, as well as a link to that post. Here's the code to display a list of your posts. (taken from the website I linked you)

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So just swap out `{{ content }}` in your `bl.html` layout with that code snippet and you've got what you want.

Additionally, if you **also want to display the content/excerpt in the list of posts**, just add the liquid tag `{{ post.content }}` or `{{post.excerpt}}` like so:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      {{ post.content }} /* or post.excerpt */
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Of course, edit the HTML accordingly for your preference. Read the documentation on [how to set up post excerpts here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts), which uses the `<!--more-->` comment separator for excerpts.

I strongly recommend reading the JekyllRb documentation for more information, it's a lot to read and not always easily understandable, but keep referring to it and you'll understand more in no time.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @matrixanomaly for your concise description. This has helped me enormously.

Comment: @AlvinSovereign glad to have helped. I have updated an incorrect link on post excerpts for your reference as well